# Edit rejected, but near identical edit approved - simple anomaly?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I enjoy editing posts for readability and clarity - I see it as a challenge to decipher difficult to understand posts and attempt to get an answerable question out of it for the submitter. Much to my dismay I recently got the "Some of your previous edits were rejected" message so I've been looking through those, and I have a question:

I made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7600424) to a post that in my opinion was very unclear. Someone else also made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7600407) that to me looks pretty much the same. Now I'm glad of course that the post was cleaned up and I don't think my edit was better (in fact, the other looks to be superior). I do have a question about the reviews given on my edit though!

**Edit:** note that my edit was registered as an edit to the other edit. My edit wasn't designed to edit the post at the state it was in in the diff shown in my edit, but to improve upon [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29491635/1).

Two reviewers rejected it with the following message:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

One even said:

> This adds a ton of fluff. The original post was fine.

Is this simply an anomaly or was my edit wrong? Did the other edit simply not get the chance to get the same kind of rejections before being accepted? Or is there something I should do to improve my edits?

Thanks!

Comment: Alright, so should I refrain from editing posts to improve the sentence structuring and/or vocabulary in the post? So I shouldn't attempt to improve on posts that I find merely understandable in the hope to make them as clear as possible?

Comment: BoltClock seems to have figured out what really happened: my edit was registered as an edit on the other edit, instead of on the original post. Do you think the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29491635/1) was clear enough as well?

Comment: Ok, in this case I retract my comments - the original post could surely deal with some editing (even though it's not unclear); your linked suggested edit just did not show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit actually came about a minute after the other edit was approved by the OP. The other edit might have been approved while you were still working on yours. I'm not sure if the system would have notified you of that happening in this case.

Whether those who reviewed your edit were aware of the context I'm not sure (the real "original post" was what it was before the other edit since it came first, and that was... [pretty bad](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29491635/1)), but in the grand scheme of things it would stand to reason that since the post was already edited to sound better once, it didn't need a second makeover.

I would chalk this one up to a misunderstanding on part of both the editors and the reviewers.

Comment: Oh, I think you're right! It seems like my edit was registered as an edit on the other edit. Makes a lot more sense for people to reject it then, since it doesn't add anything to that edit. It is weird though that the system doesn't account for that happening.